Only blank pages when exporting PowerBI report pages via PowerAutomate flow
I'm encountering a problem where the PowerAutomate flow, which is supposed to automatically send specific pages of a PowerBI report to a set of recipients specified by a Sharepoint list, is generating a PDF file with only blank pages. This is a recurring issue that I need assistance with.
The flow runs fine; it matches the example provided by the Microsoft Learn for the most part.
Despite the flow running smoothly without any errors or warnings, the resulting PDF file is a series of blank pages. This is in stark contrast to the expected visuals.
I've made numerous attempts to troubleshoot this issue, including exporting the report to PPTX and PNG formats. Unfortunately, both files were corrupted and repair tools were ineffective in resolving the issue.
Has anyone previously encountered this error or have any insights into what might be causing it? Your expertise would be greatly appreciated in resolving this issue.
Note that everything works as expected when I export the report via the desktop app.

I was also having this issue. I stumbled across another article from the Power Automate Community, where the solution is to turn off the "New Designer" slider when you are editing the flow. I tried this solution, and it worked for me as well.
It seems that when you turn off the New Designer, the attachment in the Send Email function is "Body" instead of the PowerBI file content.
Here's the link to the Power Automate Community Post where the solution came from.
Hope that helps.
